# Is it possible to create a header for each individual cell in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working on a UICollectionView that needs to display two pieces of information. First it needs to display an image, which I've done by setting it to the background view.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell:UICollectionViewCell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell;
    cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: introViewCollectionArray[indexPath.row].image)
    return cell;
}
```

I have a string I also need to display above the image. The string is different for each image, but can be accessed using

```
introViewCollectionArray[indexPath.row].note
```

It looks like setting up a header for the entire UICollectionView is possible, but I don't see a way to have a header for each cell with the text content. Have I missed something, or do I need to approach this differently?

Comment: Can I make a header for the cell and not the entire UICollectionView? I can't find any references to any methods that would do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a supplementaryView or a decorationView to each cell, you do this by subclassing a collectionView layout or, more probably, a UICollectionViewFlowLayout

You may have a look at [Apple Flow Layout documention](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html) and this [decorationView tutorial](https://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/decorationviews/)